# Why doesn't my PHP code echo out $_POST data?

Tags: javascript, php

The XHR Request shown here is sending an array to process.php. The array just contains strings ex.['hello', 'name'].

```
var xmlHTTP;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlHTTP = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4 && xmlHTTP.status == 200)
    {
          alert(this.responseText);
    }
}
var queryString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < all_data.length; i++)
{
    queryString += "data"+i.toString()+"=" + all_data[i];
    if(i < all_data.length - 1)
    {
           queryString += "&";
    }
}
xmlHTTP.open("POST", "www.example.com/process.php", true);
xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHTTP.send(queryString);
```

The PHP code below is just designed to echo out the POST data. As just a test, I wanted to see what the value of `data0` would be, but when I go to www.example.com/process.php, I get an error `Notice: Undefined index: data0 in /var/www/html/process.php on line 2`. However, when I navigate back to the page where the javascript is, it alerts the response with the correct data that was sent. Why doesn't the data be shown in the PHP file?

```
<?php
        echo $_POST["data0"];
?>
```

Comment: "*when I go to www.example.com/process.php*" That's a GET request, not POST.

Comment: hmmm not sure what you mean. In my PHP code, if I type in ```echo 'hello';``` and go to www.example.com/process.php, The page has hello written on it. I just want the same thing except with the $_POST data.

Comment: There is no POST data in a GET request.

Comment: try this answer below. Thanks. Its a GET request.

Comment: You can't just visit the link directly and expect to see returned data from a completely different request.

Comment: @gre_gor Can you explain more of what you mean? The XHR request I am making is a POST request. So shouldn't I expect a POST request in my PHP that should be accessible using $_POST? Why are you mentioning GET? I used BurpSuite to see the request being sent and it is indeed a POST request with a body with the correct data.

Comment: Open you process.php and add this var_dump $_POST['data']; to see what coming from the post. Check the answer below.

Comment: Your AJAX request and you visiting `www.example.com/process.php` "to see the data", are two separate requests.

Comment: @gre_gor Ok I kind of see what you mean. But is there a way where I can echo out the contents of that post request to that page somehow?

Comment: You are already doing it with an alert?

Comment: yes but not on the page I want it to be on. the Javascript code and php code are on 2 different pages.

Comment: Then use a form and make the same script handle both.

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code in my environment and it worked exactly as expected.

I created the `index.html` file with the **javascript** code involved by the `<script>` tag and i created the `process.php` file with your **php** code.

I set all_data to `["hello", "name"]`

Thus, when opening `index.html` in **browser**, the **XHR** call is made to `process.php` and "hello" (`data0`) is returned accordingly.

Perhaps your mistake is in trying to access `process.php` **directly**(without po), instead of executing the **javascript** code. The **javascript** should be make the call to PHP.

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also get to see the data returned correctly in ```index.html```. My issue is, I want to see the data in ```process.php```. I do not want the data to be returned to the ```index.html``` page. Perhaps using an XHR request was not the correct solution. I just want to pass an array from Javascript to PHP.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your need, to try to help.

You want to pass an array via POST from javascript to php, and process it on the php side.

But after php processing, what do you want to do?

An important detail. If you make a call from the frontend (javascript) to the backend (php), the frontend is waiting for a response to do something. This can be to present information to the user, or to perform an action, such as redirecting to another php page. Depending on your need, it may be more interesting to submit a form via POST than to make an Ajax / XHR request. []'s

Comment: I appreciate your response. What I wanted to do was pass the array from javascript to PHP thats all. I ended up using a form to send the array after I converted to JSON using ```JSON.stringify(all_data)```, to my PHP code. I am new to all of this and naturally thought that if I needed to send data from client-side to server-side I had to use an AJAX request. Not sure why people downvoted my post. I tried to explain to the best of my ability what I wanted to happen and what I expected vs what I got. I responded quickly to comments and tried to make things more clear.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry for the delay in responding. I'm new here at stackoverflow .. I thought it was unfair for people to downvoted your post, because I think doubts are doubts, and they exist at all levels. As for your problem, I believe that it is best to submit a form by the `POST` method, using` form.submit () `or something similar so that the http request is even sent and` process.php` can take over and from there do what you want .. good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much. That is what I did. It worked! I am new to stack overflow and new to programming too.